# Html output now show in Usercontrol of WPF

Tags: c#, html, xml, wpf

> I use this code but html output not display in usercontrol of WPF. Add html code in WebBrowser using by NavigateToString but blank screen is show .and no error occurred. [image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsForm_CRM_MDI.View.UserControls.DailyStatsNewUC"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsForm_CRM_MDI.View.UserControls"
         >
<Grid Background="#EEEEEE">

            <WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="200"
                Margin="10,10,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="200"
                x:Name="MainBrowser" />
             <Button Content="ok" Click="Button_Click" Height="50" Width="80"></Button> </Grid>
```

> CS Code

```
 private string CreateHTML()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ' -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\''http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>");
        builder.AppendLine("<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content - Type' content='text / html; charset = utf - 8' />< meta http - equiv = 'X-UA-Compatible' content = 'IE=edge,chrome=1' /></head>");
        builder.AppendLine("<body>");
        builder.AppendLine("<a href=\"http://stackexchange.com/users/5852250\">");
        builder.AppendLine("<img src=\"http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5852250.png?theme=dark\" width=\"208\" height=\"58\" alt=\"profile for Felix D. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\" title=\"profile for Felix D. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\">");
        builder.AppendLine("</a>");
        builder.AppendLine("</body>");
        builder.AppendLine("<html>");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         string  HtmlToDisplay = CreateHTML();
         this.MainBrowser.NavigateToString(HtmlToDisplay);

    }
```

Comment: I am using  width 200. of button and  WebBrowser element, Button are in the same grid  after then facing same  problem  and  also iam not using StackPanel and DockPanel.

Comment: I have tried in my code.

Comment: Please check the code Width="200"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197270/discussion-between-neeta-paliwal-and-clemens).

Comment: Even if the html is incorrect (missing html close tag, etc.), it works.